# Convert unix date to integer value

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, dos2unix

hi i have my UNIX file date in particular format `2017-02-01` i want to convert it in integer value like `20170201`. What can i do get this output.My **UNIX** box is(SunOS 5.10).I tried to check below command to see what they output.But i am not getting anything.Can anyone help?

```
bash-3.2$ date +'%s'
%s
bash-3.2$ date +"%s"
%s
bash-3.2$ date +%s
%s
```

When i try **date -d "Filename" +%Y%m%d** option it error out saying:-

```
date: bad conversion
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
```

Comment: What do the docs say about the value for `+format`?

Comment: Docs like? man date??

Comment: Yes, `man date`. What format specifiers are allowed in the `+format` argument? Something like `"+%Y%m%d"` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the date you like with this line of code (bash):

```
date +"%Y%m%d"
```

you can use it as a filename like this:

```
_now=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
_file="/tmp/$_now.ext"
```

then use $_file for your filename

Comment: @Oliver it is working fine but it only gives me current date value as integer value.How to make it work for a particular file???

Comment: @ghoti it only gives me current system date in integer value . I want to do it for a particular file.???

Comment: @Oliver can you explain me how it works? Like i have a file called "crontest.sh" now how can i use this in above code to get its creation date as INTEGER value.Thanks

Comment: @TusharSharma could you explain a little bit more, what you want to archive? Do you want to create a file by your crontest.sh? Perhaps an sql-dump or something like this?

Comment: @Oliver file is already there with name for ex: "abc.txt" ignore the above example.I have this file creation time and date.I want to convert its creation date to integer value like ( this 2017-02-01 to 20170201).

Comment: @Oliver in your solution (date +"%Y%m%d") where should i specify the file name to get its creation date in integer value?? Currently if i execute only this(date +"%Y%m%d") then it shows current date in integer value ex:(2017-02-07 to 20170207).How to make it work for my file "abc.txt".

Comment: ok, now I think I have understood what you want. And I have bad news for you. This is not possible in nearly all kind of unix systems. You can check that in your sun-os by using the stat command (e.g. stat -c '%w' abc.txt), but this does not work in most LINUX-systems and it depends on your filesystem. Check also the POSIX - Standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html

Comment: @Oliver i used substring to get year,month,date in different variable and then concatenate them that solved the issue. Even though not a good practice.BTW thanks a lot for your help and support.

Comment: @Oliver, while the `stat` command only exists in more modern OSs, the system call it wraps around, [`fstat(2)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fstat&sektion=2) is part of POSIX.1, so it's available in virtually *every* unix. Have a look at my answer for how to leverage the system call in a tiny C program.

Comment: @ghoti You are right, but the problem was not a missing function. It is the fact that most Linux-Systems don't use the "birthdate"-value of a file. Thats why stat or fstat does not give back the creation-date of a file.

Answer (score 0):

SunOS 5.10 (Solaris 10) is pretty old. There are some things it doesn't do.

In particular, I note that its `date` command relies on `strftime()` for formatting, and [according to the man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strftime&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS+5.10&arch=default&format=html), Solaris 10's strftime does not support `%s`. Which explains the results in the test you did in your question.

If you really just want a YYYYMMDD format, the following should work:

```
$ date '+%Y%m%d'
```

If you're looking for an epoch second, then you might have to use some other tool. Nawk, for example, should be installed on your system:

```
$ nawk 'BEGIN{print srand}'
```

You can `man nawk` and search for `srand` to see why this works.

Alternately, you could use Perl, if you've installed it:

```
$ perl -e 'print time . "\n";'
```

These are strategies to get the current epoch second, but your initial `date` command is the correct way to get the date formatted the way you suggested.

---

Based on other comments, it also appears you're looking to get the timestamp of certain files.  That's not something the `date` command will do. In other operating systems, like Linux or FreeBSD, you'd use the `stat` command, which does not appear as a separate shell command in Solaris 10.

But you can do it yourself in a pretty short C program that uses the [`fstat(2)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fstat&manpath=SunOS+5.10) system call. While it may be beyond the scope required for this question, you can probably compile this using `/usr/sfw/bin/gcc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct tm info;
    char buf[80];
    struct stat fileStat;
    time_t epoch;

    if(argc != 2)
        return 1;

    int file=0;
    if((file=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY)) < -1)
        return 1;

    if(fstat(file,&fileStat) < 0)
        return 1;

    info = *localtime( &fileStat.st_mtime );

    epoch = mktime(&info);
    printf("%s:%ld\n", argv[1], (long) epoch );

    return 0;
}
```

For example:

```
$ gcc -o filedate filedate.c
$ ./filedate /bin/ls
/bin/ls:1309814136
$ perl -e 'use POSIX; print POSIX::strftime("%F %T\n", gmtime(1309814136));'
2011-07-04 21:15:36
$ ls -l /bin/ls
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin        18700 Jul  4  2011 /bin/ls
$
```

Comment: how can this command (date '+%Y%m%d') can be used with a file?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "with a file"?  Are you trying to programatically determine the date of a file and store it in a variable?  Or are you trying to make a filename that is based on the current date? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED IT WITH THIS COMMAND-:**

```
browserDate="2016-11-21"
dateConversion="${browserDate//'-'}"
```